# Page is messed up when I choose to print it. How to keep the same format?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a simple user friendly to print page with some simple css and html code.
here it is how it looks like

**`Screenshot of actual page`**
[image]

The problem is that when I press the CTRL+P to print the current page, the preview is a mess as shown below.

My question is how can I keep the format of my created php file when someone wants to print the page?

This is the CSS I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/settings.css" media="screen" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
```

**`screenshot of the print preview page`**
[image]

Comment: are you including all of your stylesheets for all media types, or just screen?

Comment: @sevenseacat What I do is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/settings.css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">`

Comment: @Karoumpas Your links are easier to see if you just edit them into the question - I took the liberty of doing that for you.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you should make new rules for print:

```
@media screen {
    /* screen rules */
}
@media print {
  /* print rules */
}
@media screen,print {
    /* global rules */
}
```

If you'd like to abstract all these rules in a unique file, something like this will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css"  media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: So to clear my mind.. In my print.php I have several stylesheets where i set `media="screen"`. I did not understand though what to do with the new unique file, what to include into the print rules

Comment: @Karoumpas This is a good starting point: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/